# Labelling contour levels with personalized labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contour

I would like to label contour levels in a density plot, with personalized labels. I have written something like

```
contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 3, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, levels=[1,2], fontsize=8)

plt.imshow(Z, extent=[0, 5, 0, 5], origin='lower',
       cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar();
```

I would like that the contours are labelled by a name like `r'\textbf{1-}'+r'$\sigma$'`

Comment: How exactly would you like the text to relate to the contour? Like what should the text of the first contour be like compared to the second?

Comment: with a list of string. The first string would correspond to the first level and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is directly shown in the second example of the [contour_label_demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_label_demo.html). 
I will just quote that example here:

> ```
> ##################################################
> # Label contours with arbitrary strings using a
> # dictionary
> ##################################################
> plt.figure()
>
> # Basic contour plot
> CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
>
> fmt = {}
> strs = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh']
> for l, s in zip(CS.levels, strs):
>     fmt[l] = s
>
> # Label every other level using strings
> plt.clabel(CS, CS.levels[::2], inline=True, fmt=fmt, fontsize=10)
> ```